# Type inheritance in Dictionary<ulong,BaseObject>

Tags: c#, inheritance, dictionary, types, generics

Here's the situation:
There's a base class of type `BaseObject` ,from which all other classes are derived(i.e. `Task : BaseObject`).
There's also a base class collection of type `BaseObjectCollection` which inherits from `Dictionary<ulong,BaseObject>` and some other collections that inherit from it (i.e. `TaskCollection:BaseObjectCollection`).
When iterating over `TaskCollection` members they are shown as `BaseObject` type.
Is there any way to make the collection "change" its values' types so that it will possess the functionality of `BaseobjectCollection` and yet appear as `Dictionary<ulong,Task>` instead of `Dictionary<ulong,BaseObject>`

Comment: I am using C# language in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `BaseObjectCollection` type to be generic in the type of value it will use. For example:

```
public class BaseObjectCollection<T> : Dictionary<ulong, T>
    where T : BaseObject
```

Then you can use a `BaseObjectCollection<Task>` and still be completely type-safe.

(I would personally use composition in most cases rather than deriving a new type from `Dictionary<,>` but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ,that was an eyeopening for me, as I'm only a newbie to the generic types.
By the way, why do you prefer composition rather that using Dictionary?